# Water potential problem

Tags: osmosis

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Left cell} \qquad& \text{Right cell} \\
\Psi_w=\pu{-1400 kPa} \qquad& \Psi_w=\pu{-600kPa} \\
\Psi_p=\pu{600 kPa} \qquad& \Psi_p=\pu{800kPa} \\
\Psi_s=\pu{-2000 kPa} \qquad& \Psi_s=\pu{-1400kPa} \\
\end{align*}
$$

This is the data given, and we have to find the water potential, solute potential and pressure potential at equilibrium. I can't seem to find any website or video for solving these types of questions.

I tried and got the answer equilibrium water potential to be about -1000 kPa, but it seems there can be multiple answers of solute and pressure potential.

So my questions are:
In this problem, are there multiple answers for solute and pressure potential, and is my water potential answer correct?

Comment: How is this a question about biology?

Comment: It is in my biology textbook. And I think it's part of A level biology course as well.

Comment: Biology is the study of life. Your question makes no reference to any living organism. It also presents the problem as a graphic which is not permissible as it cannot be indexed and discriminates against those with visual deficiencies. Please take the trouble to write out your question properly making the biological context clear, and explaining how you arived at your answer. If the question is in a text book (please name it) then one would expect it to include the necessary information for solving the problem. What did you find there?